# How to add one object into multiple objects -JOLT

Tags: json, merge, apache-nifi, jolt

i want to merge the info key data into the rest objects

```json
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "item": "banana",
      "value": 3
    },
    {
      "item": "banana",
      "value": 3
    }
  ],
  "info": {
    "place": [
      {
        "country": "canada"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

my code:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "item": "[&1].&",
          "value": "[&1].price",
          "@2,info.place": {
            "*": {
              "country": "[&1].&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

output:

```json
[
  {
    "country": [ "canada", "canada" ],
    "item": "banana",
    "price": 3
  },
  {
    "item": "banana",
    "price": 3
  }
]
```

so country should not be an array, of course, i can use cardinality to remove the array but country is not added to the last object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should track the index of `data` array, not of `place` array so that to walk the indexes **0** and **1**, to not stay only on the index **0**.

So, you should convert **`[&1]`** to **`[&3]`** next to `"country"` key such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "item": "[&1].&",
          "value": "[&1].price",
          "@2,info.place": {
            "*": {
              "country": "[&3].&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

which will yield

```json
[
  {
    "country": "canada",
    "item": "banana",
    "price": 3
  },
  {
    "country": "canada",
    "item": "banana",
    "price": 3
  }
]
```